# Checking if the image is loaded within specific timespan

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to load image with JS and give it a certain time to load. For example 1 second. If the image wasn't loaded within 1 second - use default image. Here's what I have so far:

```
function displayUserImage() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var imageMe = new Image();
        imageMe.onload = function(){
            $('#user-img-me').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageMe.src + ')');
        };
        imageMe.onerror = function() {
            imageMe.src = "images/defaultImage.png";
        }

        if(!isEmpty(myObject.getPic()) && !isBlank(myObject.getPic())) {
            imageMe.src = myObject.getPic();
        }
        else {
            imageMe.src = "images/defaultImage.png";
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

I'm setting timeOut of 0 only to make the image loading asynchronous and not to interfere with execution of rest of the code. `myObject.getPic()` returns a string with image path. The image may be located on a remote domain/server. The connection might be slow, the image might be heavy, the server may not respond... So I want to give this image only a second to load, and if it didn't succeed - use default image. In both cases I need to set external variable `imageMeLoaded` to true once either image is loaded. Can it be done?

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), you'll find `complete` property. With that you should get the task done. Notice, that image loading is always asynchronous. You don't need extra timeout here.

Comment: Thanks! I think it helped.